# WPF ListView places garbage into a log file

Tags: c#, listview

When i try to save my list view lines into a log file using StreamWriter:

```
sw.WriteLine(listview.Items[0]);
```

it places to the beginning of the line name of LIstViewItem class, and my log looks like:

```
System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem: text text text;
```

I tried to use:

```
sw.WriteLine(listView.Items[0].ToString());
```

and:

```
sw.WriteLine(listView.Items[0].ToString() as string);
```

but nothing helpes:(

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the console will use the `ToString()` method as the output. All of the methods you have tried will be using the `ToString()` method.

Perhaps you are looking for the `Text` property.

```
sw.WriteLine(((ListViewItem)listview.Items[0]).Text);
```

Comment: Sorry, there is no such propery as .Text in Items :(

Comment: there are no properties in listview.Items[0], only 4 Object standard methods

Comment: I've edited my answer, you need to cast the item in the collection to a `ListViewItem`.

Comment: System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem has no such property as .Text too(

Answer (score 0):

The ListView.Items property is an ItemCollection.  The items contained are typed as Object.  You must cast the item to whatever type you populated the ListView with and then access the appropriate property from there.  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms605127(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.items(v=vs.110).aspx for more information.